# How can i compare two columns in andWhere method?

Tags: php, yii2

I have two columns `used` and `maxUsed` and I want to compare those columns.

This is my code (Yii2):

```
...->andWhere(['or', ['maxUse' => 0] , [ '<' , 'used' , 'maxUse' ]])..
```

Executed SQL is :

```
... AND ((`maxUse`=0) OR (`used` < 'maxUse'))...
```

In this statement there is no error but the SQL query is incorrect. I want compare maxUse no 'maxUse' as string

I need this :

```
... AND ((`maxUse`=0) OR (`used` < `maxUse`))
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: in this statement there is no error but sql query is incorrect . i want compare maxUse no 'maxUse' as string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find any solution and finally solved it by raw text:

```
...->andWhere('maxUse = 0 or used < maxUse');
```

Comment: yes it works fine you just need to remove [ ]                                 ->where(['>','stock.total_sale', 'stock.total_purchase']) <- not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
...->andWhere(['or', ['maxUse' => 0] , '`used` < `maxUse`'])
```

EDIT: or this (database independent quoting)

```
...->andWhere(['or', ['maxUse' => 0] , '[[used]] < [[maxUse]]'])
```

Comment: Now , i get this error : Operator '`USED` < `MAXUSE`' requires two operands.

Comment: I added Quoting Table and Column Names, try now

Comment: erro again: `Operator '[[USED]] < [[MAXUSE]]' requires two operands` . please test it first yourself :)

Comment: @hadiaj sorry didnt have much time, you have to of course drop array there, edited it and tested :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ('and' , 'or') for first value of any array. condition careated recursively.

```
$query->andWhere(['OR', ['AND', 
                                ['oprator', 'attribute', 'value'],
                                ['oprator2', 'attribute2', 'value2']
                        ], ['attribute3' => 'value3']])
```

Comment: i know i you can use ('and' , 'or') but there is no value, i want to compare two columns .